# Much | Then | Turn on

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, word-choice

> Seen  from  this  perspective,  the  tension  in  chapter  five  dissolves, but Mill is scarcely out of the woods because **much then
>   turns on** the determination of relevant harm.
>
> *The Moral Foundation of Politics by Ian Shapiro [pp. 62]*

For this sentence I have got some questions:

- What does **much** refer to? (woods?)
- What does **then** means? Just what it says or taken with "much" like **much then**?
- And most importantly: What does **turns on** means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Cambridge Dictionary, **[much](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/much)** means "a large amount", and **[then](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/then)** means "at that time" or "next", and **[turn on](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turn-on-something)** means "depend on" in this context.

> Seen from this perspective, the tension in chapter five dissolves, but Mill is scarcely [out of the woods/safe] because [much/a large amount] then [turns on/depends on] the determination of relevant harm.

It is not clear from this short sentence whether **then** refers to the situation at the end of chapter five [at that time], or what might happen in chapters six, seven, etc [next]. It is probably more likely to mean **next**.

Comment: I think "much" refers to "much of these woods(problems)". Am I right?

Comment: **Woods** are not problems- they are a place where problems exist- problems like bears, the risk of accidental injury or getting lost, etc. When you are 'out of the woods', it means that you have escaped safely from a dangerous place. In this sentence, **much** does not refer to problems- it refers to what might happen next.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Seen from this perspective, the tension in chapter five dissolves, but Mill is scarcely *out of problems/danger* (out of the woods) because [Mill] *in that situation rather/in fact* (much then) *activates* (turns on) the determination of relevant harm.

Comment: I think that you are mistaken about the interpretation of **turns on**. See the dictionary definition I provided in my answer.

Comment: @JavaLatte I have a hard time constructing a causality (because) with your translation. Is it possible not to be out of danger _because_ one depends on the determination of relevant harm? I'd rather say the determination is a consequence of not being safe or it's as sign for not being safe.

Comment: Which meaning of determination are you thinking of? I'm going for this one "the process of finding something out" https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/determination , which gives "because a lot then depends on finding out the relevant harm". But the sentence is typical political-philosophical bulls**t, and the writer has gone out of his way to conceal the meaning.